# Failsafe Plugin multiple executions of same goal for different phases doesnt work

Tags: maven, maven-failsafe-plugin

The failsafe plugin code below is intended to populate a target server with subscriber records during the pre-integration-test phase and delete them again in the post-integration-test phase . 
There are JMeter plugins bound to the integration-test phase which carry out performance tests .

```
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.16</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>create-subscribers</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <test>AbcIntegrationIT#registerSubscriberGroup</test>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>delete-subscribers</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <test>AbcIntegrationIT#deleteSubscriberGroup</test>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

The first execution of this plugin runs OK and the performance test run fine . 
However the second execution doesn't as , according to Failsafe

[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.16:integration-test (delete-subscribers) @ digihost-integration-test-apm ---
[INFO] Skipping execution of surefire because it has already been run for this configuration

!?

I would argue that yes it has run for the pre-integration-test phase but not for the post-integration-test phase .

It looks as if other plugins do support multi-phase executions for a single goal (viz. cobertura plugin [Running maven goal in multiple lifecycles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103386/running-maven-goal-in-multiple-lifecycles) ) , which leads me to wonder if this is a bug in Failsafe

Any Thoughts and Feedback greatly appreciated .

Comment: I'd try the latest version of the plugin, which is 2.18.1.  May not help, but it's the first thing.

Comment: same result with 2.18.1 but thanks for pointing that out - need to cover off the basics first !